How to use json data from an existing object to update an other object?
Here is my first input (recorded as bash var $services)
It can contain multiple key based values.
[
{
  "key": "movies-wikibase-jobrunner",
  "subPath": "LocalSettings.php",
  "cm": "movies-wikibase-jobrunner-localsettings-override-php"
},
{
  "key": "movies-wikibase-jobrunner",
  "subPath": "jobrunner-entrypoint.sh",
  "cm": "movies-wikibase-jobrunner-jobrunner-entrypoint-sh"

},
{
  "key": "movies-wikibase-wdqs-frontend",
  "subPath": "wdqs_front_index.html",
  "cm": "movies-wikibase-wdqs-frontend-index-html"
}
]


I'd like to use subPath to update deployment.json.
{
 "spec": {
  "template": {
   "spec": {
    "containers": [
     {
      "volumeMounts": [
       {
        "mountPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html",
        "name": "movies-wikibase-wdqs-frontend-index-html",
        "subPath": "wdqs_front_index.html"
}]}]}}}}

I tried to pass subPath as a bash argument to jq but nothing works
cat deployment.json | jq -r --arg services $services                                
  '.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[]? |=
   { mountPath: .mountPath, name: (.key, subPath: $services
  |select(.key=="movies-wikibase-wdqs-frontend").subPath) }'

How can I achieve this, and is this the good way?

What do you mean "update deployment.json"?  How exactly do you expect that file to be updated?

An obvious problem with the posted attempt is that you haven't quoted $services.  It should be enclosed in double-quotation marks.  If that doesn't solve the problem, then please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

"but nothing works" – I'm not sure what that means. What is the output when you run your command? (but if your variable content really contains spaces like your example, user peak is spot on)

jq --argjson services "$services" '
   .|=
    (
      .metadata.name as $name |
         | .spec.template.spec.containers[]?.volumeMounts[]? 
      . += { subPath: ($services[] | select(.key == $name).subPath // .subPath) }
    )
' deployment.json > updated_deployment.json


EDIT
Addressing Multiple Entries with the same key
When multiple entries in $services have the same key and you want to handle all corresponding subPath values. You could transform the $services input to group them by key, and then iterate over these groups when updating the JSON
Transform
Creates a new structure where each key is associated with a list of subPath
grouped_services=$(echo $services | jq 'group_by(.key) | map({key: .[0].key, subPaths: map(.subPath)})') 
Second command
jq --argjson services "$grouped_services" '
  .spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[] |=
    (
      .name as $name |
      . + { mountPath: ($services[] | select(.key == $name).subPaths[] // .mountPath) }
    )
' deployment.json > updated_deployment.json

group_by(.key): This jq function groups your service entries by their key, making it easier to handle entries under the same key.D
map({key: .[0].key, subPaths: map(.subPath)}): This reformats the grouped data so each group has a single key and an array of subPath values (subPaths).
select(.key == $name).subPaths[]: This part of the jq filter selects the grouped entry matching the name (used as a key) and iterates over all subPath values. If no match is found, it defaults to the existing mountPath.

While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

This solution doesn't solve the case where there are multiple entries for the same keys. In this case, only the first occurrence is taken. We should iterate as well on the subPath list. It try with grouping by key with echo $services| jq 'group_by(.key)[]|{key: .[0].key, value:[.[] | {subPath: .subPath}]}'|jq -s but I'm stuck

A simple bash loop based answer
for i in $services |jq -r '.key'|uniq);
do
  pair=$(echo $services| jq -r --arg i "$i" 'select(.key==$i).subPath'
    for j in $pair;
      do 
        cat $i-deployment.json | 
        jq -r --arg subPath $j \
        '(.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts+=[{subPath: $subPath}])' | sponge $i-deployment.json
      done
done

